# Google Scripts - Grab email address from bounced message and parse information

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, gmail-api

Good Morning,

I am a newbie to javascript, google scripts, and regex. I have found very good information from Amit Agarwal at https://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-bounced-email-report/29209/, but I'm having difficulty identifying what I specifically need to keep or need to update. Rather than using the bounce mailer-daemon addresses, I would like to grab the bounced messages from two labels in my gmail account (MinervaBounce and MILSBounce) and be able to differentiate which one the message came from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the items that are needed from the bounce message:

1. Email date
2. Label name
3. Bounce email address
4. Bounce reason
5. Library name from message body
6. Bounce Message

Here is an example of the bounce message text:

The original message was received at Tue, 31 Jul 2018 07:16:38 -0400
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----

    (reason: 554 5.7.1 < margolulubelle@gwi.net >: Recipient address rejected: user margolulubelle@gwi.net does not exist)

----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to mx.gwi.net.cust.b.hostedemail.com.:

> > > DATA
> > >       <<< 554 5.7.1 < margolulubelle@gwi.net >: Recipient address rejected: user margolulubelle@gwi.net does not exist
> > >       554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
> > >       <<< 554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients

---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: library.noreply@library.org
To:  margolulubelle@gwi.net
Cc: 
Bcc: 
Date:  Tue, 31 Jul 2018 07:16:38 -0400
Subject: Circulation Notice From Your Library

07-31-18 07:16PM

```
Fremont Memorial Library
555 Fremont Ave
Freedom, ME 04941

        Margo Madeup-Name
        555 Dartmouth Ln
        Dixfield, ME 04224

 ******************************************************************
                 LIBRARY REQUEST / HOLD CANCELLED
 ******************************************************************
 YOUR REQUEST FOR THE FOLLOWING MATERIAL COULD NOT BE FILLED, OR THE
 HOLD WAS FULFILLED, BUT NOT PICKED UP IN TIME. CONTACT YOUR LIBRARY
 TO PURSUE OTHER AVENUES TO OBTAIN OR RE-REQUEST THE ITEM.
```

AUTHOR: 
   Blue Green Yellow Red
   CALL NO: FIC BLU
   BARCODE: 3400599999
   Fremont PL Children's Rm

88:1

Here is Amit's code:

```js
/*

* Gmail Bounced Emails
* @labnol December 14, 2016
* Written by Amit Agarwal

* email: amit@labnol.org
* twitter: @labnol
* web: https://ctrlq.org

*/

function onOpen(e) {  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(" Gmail")
  .addItem("Bounce Report", "b_")
  .addItem("Help and Support", "h_")
  .addToUi();  
  h_(false);
}

function b_(){var e=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();e.getRange(2,1,e.getLastRow(),e.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
var t="in:anywhere from:(mailer-daemon@google.com OR mailer-daemon@googlemail.com)",a='=HYPERLINK("URL";"View")',o=0;GmailApp.search(t,0,500).forEach(function(t){t.getMessages().forEach(function(r){if(r.getFrom().indexOf("mailer-daemon")!==-1){var i=r.getPlainBody(),l=i.match(/Delivery to[\s\S]+?(\S+\@\S+)\s([\s\S]+?)-----/)||i.match(/Your message wasn't delivered to (\S+\@\S+) ([\s\S]+)/);
if(l){var n=l[2].match(/The response.+:\s+(.+)/)||l[2].match(/The error.+:\s+(.+)/)||l[2].match(/Technical details.+:\s+(.+)/)||["",l[2].trim()];o++,e.appendRow([t.getLastMessageDate(),l[1],n[1].replace(/ (Please|Learn|See).*$/,""),a.replace("URL",t.getPermalink()),t.getFirstMessageSubject()])}}}),Utilities.sleep(100)}),0===o&&(o="ZERO"),h_(o)}

function h_(e){var t=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("help");t.report=e?"The Google Script found COUNT bounced emails in your mailbox.".replace("COUNT",e):"Please go to the  Gmail menu and select Bounce Report to get started.";
var a=t.evaluate().setTitle("Bounce Report for Gmail").setWidth(460).setHeight(225);SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(a)}
```

Thank you,
Lynn

Comment: In your scenario what does Amit's code return for you?

Comment: It returns my bounces not the ones that I have forwarded from other email accounts and tagged with a particular label. I exchanged the mailer daemon addresses for those (mailer-daemon@urs2.iii.com and mailer-daemon@mils.iii.com) and didn't get anything either...I'm assuming that the error text from those messages doesn't match the text in the regex, but unfortunately I can't tell where I would exactly need to edit.  I'd like to create a report for the ones with a particular label to send off to other colleagues, so they can act on them.

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the query to your  needs, it may look like this:

```
from:(mailer-daemon@googlemail.com OR mailer-daemon@google.com) AND (label:"SO Review" OR label:"Sample Wala")
```

This will get the bounce email from multiple labels (`OR` operator is needed to make it match on any label, not requiring that both label is found in an email).
Use `Users.messages: list` and the query to get the list of `messageID` that matches your query then use `threadID` to get the original message before it failed to send. Lastly use `Users.messages` to view the details about the original message.

References:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10581/filtering-based-on-multiple-labels-in-gmail